# Properties of Euclidean Algorithm

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Let $a, b$ be positive integers and $a > b$. Either prove the statement or give a counterexample.
>
> (A) $\gcd(a + b, a − b) = \gcd(a, b)$
>
> (B) $\gcd(a + b, 2a − b) = \gcd(a, b)$
>
> (C) $\gcd(a + b, 2a + b) = \gcd(a, b)$

For the first one $\gcd(a + b, a − b)= \gcd(a-b, 2b)= \gcd(a-3b, 2b)$... I'm not sure what information would lead to assertion that these gcds are equal. For example, if two gcd's can be expressed as $\gcd(x, y)$ through the Euclidean algorithm are they equal?

Comment: Have you tried some examples?

Comment: for the first one (A), they're not necessarily equal; e.g., $a=b=1$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner The problem states $a > b$, so $a=b=1$ cannot work, correct?

Comment: @Hendrix:  Oops, I missed that; you're correct; how about $a=3, b=1$

Comment: You will probably get answers but we sort of frown on multiple-question questions. What if three people each gave a great answer to one each of your three questions? Who gets the best answer vote? We also want you to show us something that you tried. Even if it failed. We call that "context". It gives us an idea of what level of skill you are at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hints:**

1. For (B), what if $\ a\equiv 2\ (\hspace{-0,7em}\mod 3) \ $ and $\ b\equiv 1\ (\hspace{-0,7em}\mod 3) \ $?
2. For (C), note that $\ a = (2a+b)-(a+b)\ $, and $\ b=2(a+b)-(2a + b)\ $, so any divisor of both $\ a+b\ $ and $\ 2a+b\ $ is also a divisor of both $\ a\ $ and $\ b\ $.

Answer (score 2):

For (A), how about $a=3, b=1$?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1254378)

Comment: @MostafaAyaz:  the other answer addressed (B) and (C), so I gave a counterexample to answer (A)